# Prove that $x^p+y^p \equiv (x+y)^p \pmod{x^2+xy+y^2}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p > 3$ be a prime, and let $x,y$ be integers such that $\gcd(x,y) = 1$. Prove that $$x^p+y^p \equiv (x+y)^p \pmod{x^2+xy+y^2}.$$

I thought about expanding $(x+y)^p$ using the binomial theorem, but I didn't see how that would help because the modulus is an algebraic expression. How can we prove the statement?

Comment: Possible hint: $\,(x+1)^p - x^p - 1\,$ is divisible by $\,x^2+x+1\,$ as polynomials.

Comment: Possible hint: $x^3 - y^3 = (x - y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$0\equiv (x-y)\cdot0\equiv(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)\equiv x^3-y^3\mod (x^2+xy+y^2)$$

So that $x^3\equiv y^3 \mod (x^2+xy+y^2)$ (from now on, I mean $\mod (x^2+xy+y^2)$ if omitted).

Now note, for $p=2k+1$, that

\begin{align}
(x+y)^p&\equiv(x+y)(x+y)^{2k}\\
&\equiv(x+y)(x^2+2xy+y^2)^k\\
&\equiv(x+y)(xy)^k\\
&\equiv x^{k+1}y^k+x^ky^{k+1}\\
\end{align}

since $p$ is prime, either $k$ or $k+1$ is divisible by $3$ (if neither are, then $k+2$ is, but then $2k+4-3=2k+1=p>3$ is a prime, not three, but divisible by $3$. Contradiction). Thus, since $x^3\equiv y^3$, $x^n$ and $y^n$ are interchangeable as long as $n$ is a multiple of $3$; thus, we have two cases;

---

**Case 1: $3\mid k$.** In this case,
$$(x+y)^p\equiv x^{k+1}y^k+x^ky^{k+1}\equiv x^{k+1}x^k+y^ky^{k+1}\equiv x^p+y^p$$

**Case 2: $3\mid k+1$.** In this case,
$$(x+y)^p\equiv x^{k+1}y^k+x^ky^{k+1}\equiv y^{k+1}y^k+x^kx^{k+1}\equiv x^p+y^p$$

Thus, we conclude $(x+y)^p\equiv x^p+y^p\mod (x^2+xy+y^2)$.

---

Note that we didn't use the fact that $p$ is prime; we just used the fact that it's odd and not divisible by $3$. This proof therefore works for all numbers $p$ of the form $6k\pm1$.

---

In the comments, this question arised:

> For what $p$ can we assure $x^p+y^p\equiv (x+y)^p$?

So let me adress that. Let me also point out that $\gcd(x,y)=1$ implies $x$, $y$, and $x^2+xy+y^2$ are pairwise coprime; thus, $x$ and $y$ have inverses.

If $p$ is even (write $p=2k$):

$$(x+y)^p\equiv(x+y)^{2k}\equiv (x^2+2xy+y^2)^k\equiv x^ky^k$$

Now we need $x^{2k}+y^{2k}\equiv x^ky^k$. Write $k=3K+c$ for $c\in\{-1,0,1\}$, so that

\begin{align}
x^{2k}+y^{2k}&\equiv x^{6K}x^{2c}+y^{6K}y^{2c}\\
&\equiv y^{3K}x^{3K}x^{2c}+x^{3K}y^{3K}y^{2c}\\
&\equiv x^{3K}y^{3K}(x^{2c}+y^{2c})\\
\end{align}

And since we need this to be $x^ky^k\equiv x^{3K+c}y^{3K+c}$, we know that we should have $x^{2c}+y^{2c}\equiv x^cy^c$. Now there are three cases, because $c\in\{-1,0,1\}$.

- Let's do the easy case first: $c=0$. The expression reads $2\equiv 1$, which is only true if $x^2+xy+y^2=1$.
- Another case: $c=1$. The expression reads $x^2+y^2\equiv xy$, which means $3xy\equiv 0$, implying $3\equiv 0$. Only happens if $x^2+xy+y^2\in\{1,3\}$.
- The last case, $c=-1$:
  $x^{-2}+y^{-2}\equiv x^{-1}y^{-1}$ implying $x^2+y^2\equiv xy$, so the same as the $c=1$ case.

---

Now assume $p$ is odd and divisible by $3$. Then let $p=6k+3, so that

\begin{align}
(x+y)^p&\equiv (x+y)(x+y)^{6k+2}\\
&\equiv (x+y)(x^2+2xy+y^2)^{3k+1}\\
&\equiv (x+y)(xy)^{3k+1}\\
&\equiv x^{3k+2}y^{3k+1}+x^{3k+1}y^{3k+2}\\
\end{align}

And we want this to be equivalent to $x^{6k+3}+y^{6k+3}$, but we can rewrite that to $x^{6k+3}+y^{6k+3}\equiv x^{3k+3}y^{3k}+x^{3k+3}y^{3k}\equiv x^{3k+3}y^{3k}+x^{3k}y^{3k+3}$. Now we need to solve

$$x^{3k+2}y^{3k+1}+x^{3k+1}y^{3k+2}\equiv x^{3k+3}y^{3k}+x^{3k}y^{3k+3}$$

or, dividing by $(xy)^{3k}$,

$$x^2y+xy^2\equiv xy(x+y)\equiv (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)\equiv x^3+y^3$$

Multiply both sides by $(x+y)$ (since $(x+y)^2\equiv xy$):

$$x^2y^2\equiv xy(x^2-xy+y^2)\equiv -2x^2y^2$$

so that $0\equiv 2$, which only happens when $x^2+xy+y^2\in\{1,2\}$.

So really, only if $x^2+xy+y^2\in\{1,2,3\}$, the statement can be true for $p\neq 6k\pm1$. Now the question is; Can that happen? Does, for example, $x^2+xy+y^2=3$ have solutions? We already see that $x^2+xy+y^2$ is never $2\mod 3$, so that $x^2+xy+y^2=2$ has no solutions.

Now let's solve $x^2+xy+y^2=3$. Note $(x+y)^2=xy+3$ so that $x$ and $y$ need to be positive (it's clear, when $|x|,|y|\le3$, the only solutions are $(x,y)\in\{(-1,-1),(1,-2),(2,-1),(-1,2),(-2,1),(1,1)\}$, and since $(x+y)^2$ is positive, so is $xy+3$), so with AM-GM, we see:

$$(x+y)^2\ge (2\sqrt{xy})^2=4xy\ge xy+3xy> xy+3$$

where we use $xy>1$, since we already handled $|x|,|y|\le3$.

The same can be done for $x^2+xy+y^2=1$. We need $(x+y)^2=xy+1$, and note that the only solutions $|x|,|y|\le 1$ are $(x,y)\in\{(0,-1),(0,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,0),(1,0)\}$, so that we can again apply AM-GM:

$$(x+y)^2\ge (2\sqrt{xy})^2\ge 4xy>xy+1$$

Thus, the only solutions when $p\neq 6k\pm1$ are

$$(x,y)\in\{(-1,-1),(1,-2),(2,-1),(-1,2),(-2,1),(1,1),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,0),(1,0)\}$$

Comment: If $n$ is divisible by $3$, is it true that the congruence is never true for any $x,y$? More generally, for any $n$ which is not $6k \pm 1$.

Comment: @user19405892 No, take $x=y=1$ and $p=3$ or $p=9$ for example.

Comment: So for any other $n$ which is not of the form $6k \pm 1$, the congruence isn't always true?

Comment: @user19405892 Probably so. Some more context might help, since neither of the premises that $p$ is prime or $\gcd(x,y)=1$ were used in the posted proofs, which makes the question itself a bit odd.

Comment: @dxiv What other counterexamples did you know of other than $x = y = 1$ if $p = 6k+3$?

Comment: @user19405892 If you refer to my now deleted comment about "*infinitely many*", then that meant infinitely many values of $p\,$, precisely those of the form $p=6k+3\,$. I haven't looked for other counterexamples specifically, since this seemed to be a side question, plus the argument in the answer I posted is polynomial based, thus not the best suited to find such *counter*examples.

Comment: @user19405892 I edited my post to adress the problem described in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on previous comment: $\,(x+1)^p-x^p-1\,$ is divisible by $\,x^2+x+1\,$ as polynomials.

Let $\,\omega_1,\omega_2\,$ be the roots of $x^2+x+1\,$, and note that they are the two complex cube roots of unity since $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. By Vieta's relations $1+\omega_1+\omega_2=0\,$. It also follows that $1+\omega_1^p+\omega_2^p=0$ for any $p \ge 1$ which is not a multiple of $3\,$.

Then,  $\,P(\omega_1)=(\omega_1+1)^p-\omega_1^p-1=(-\omega_2)^p-\omega_1^p-1=-\omega_2^p-\omega_1^p-1=0\,$ for any odd $p \gt 3$ which is not a multiple of $3\,$. The same goes to show that $\,P(\omega_2)=0\,$, so $\,P(x)\,$ is a polynomial multiple of $\,(x-\omega_1)(x-\omega_2)=x^2+x+1\,$.

Let $\,(x+1)^p-x^p-1=Q(x)(x^2+x+1)\,$ where $\,Q(x)\,$ is a polynomial of degree at most $p-2$ with integer coefficients. Then:

$$\left(\frac{x}{y}+1\right)^p-\frac{x^p}{y^p}-1=Q\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac{x}{y}+1\right)$$

Multiplying by $\,y^p\,$ gives:

$$(x+y)^p-x^p-y^p=y^{p-2}Q\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \cdot \left(x^2+xy+y^2\right)$$

Quite obviously, $\,y^{p-2}Q\left(\cfrac{x}{y}\right)\,$ is an integer whenever $x,y$ are integers.

As a note, the above only used the conditions that $p > 3$ must be an odd integer not divisible by $\,3\,$ (though not necessarily a prime).

Answer (score 0):

Not true, you can use polynomial modular arithmetic, i will give an example for what i am talking about :

when $p=3$ we have $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2 y+3x y^2+y^3 $, and we want to find the remainder module $x^2+x y+y^2$ , the leading expression in the bigger polynomial is $x^3$ which means we need to multiply the smaller polynomial by $x$ and subtract from each, we arrive at $ 2 x^2 y+2 x y^2+y^3$ and the leading $x$ term is $2x^2 y$ in this new polynomial, so we need to multiply by $2y$ and subtract, we arrive at $-y^3$ which is the smallest term we can reach.

Now for the expression $(x+y)^p = ? \mod (x^2+x y+y^2)$ we have $6$ cases :

$p=6n$ => $y^{6n}$

$p=6n+1$ => $xy^{6n}+y^{6n+1}$

$p=6n+2$ => $xy^{6n+1}$

$p=6n+3$ => $-y^{6n+3}$

$p=6n+4$ => $-xy^{6n+3}-y^{6n+4}$

$p=6n+5$ => $-xy^{6n+4}$

And for the expression $x^p+y^p=? \mod (x^2+xy+y^2)$ we have $3$ cases :

$p=3n$ => $2y^{3n}$

$p=3n+1$ => $xy^{3n}+y^{3n+1}$

$p=3n+2$ => $-xy^{3n+1}$.

And because $5,5+6,5+2*6,5+3*6,5+4*6$ are all primes, one can conclude mistakenly that  it works just for primes, but actually it also works for $p=5+6*5=35$, also $p=77$.

**In General** : it works for any $p=\pm 1 \mod 6$.

**For Instance** : take $x=2,y=3,p=35$ , so $2^35+3^35 = 5^35 \mod 19$, checking it on Wolfram Alpha, they both give remainder $4$.